# Trigger a push notification from inside the app

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, apn

Is it possible to trigger a push notification from inside the app itself?

I need to build a function that compares a remote file to a cached file and if there is any new content on the remote file it updates the cache and triggers a push notification from the app itself.

I was wondering if this is possible? And if so how would I go about building it?

Note: the cached file will be in JSON format.

Comment: No you can't do that. Only a server can send a push.

Comment: at any time you may call a webservice to indicate server to send push notification in device, or you may use local notification(UILocalNotification) if you want to send from device itself

Comment: thanks @Pyro Im using UILocalNotification. But when I close the app it basically stops working. I was wondering if theres a way to keep the function running to send notifications periodically even when the app is closed.

Comment: @kevinabraham the functionality will stop when the app is close, but if you set the UILocalNotification in the app for specific time it will called even if your app is closed

Comment: @Pyro I need to check for updates on a json response. Would I be able to do this everytime before sending a UILocalNotification? or would it be better to run the check as a background fetch function?

Comment: you can whatever code you want to do before setting UILocalNotification, if condition satisfy you can set the notification, for the background fetch there is specific criteria in which apple allow it

Answer (score 1):

To make this possible, you would have to permanently check for updates, which would **drain the user's battery** and **consume networking capacity**, so setting up a server to realise this task is the way to go here.

It would look somewhat like this:

1. Send your device's push token to your server and subscribe to changes to the file.
2. Trigger action on server, when remote file changes.
3. Send notification to those devices that subscribed to the file using the push token you got in step 1.

To learn more about how push notifications work, you can have a look onto this great tutorial [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/123862/push-notifications-tutorial).

Comment: @pi000 I agree and I would have liked to do it that way. But the client wants to use local notifications instead of using a server initially which is why I asked to do it this way.